# Java JMS Persist message properties over transactions

Tags: java, jms

Within a MDB, I need to roll back at certain point for an exception.

I also need to persist some contextual error data that needs to be retrieved on the next redelivery.

Is this possible ? How to achieve such ?

I tried setting message properties, but it appears that each MDB `onMessage()` is called with a new instance for that message.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to roll back, you have to implement JMS transactions. You'll find a lot of resources on this topic.
Here is an example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2EE/DemonstratestheuseoftransactionsinaJMSapplication.htm